# gson and java.sql in Java 11?

Tags: java, maven, gson, java-11

We are trying to migrate our projects from Java 8 to Java 11 and are encountering some issues with gson.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Time
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
... 6 more
```

My assumption was that the issue was related to modularity and java.sql.Time not being added to the project. But adding `--add-modules=java.sql` has not helped and the issue remains. This has been the only recommended solution I have found while searching.

The issue is the same if I explicitly call java.sql.Time myself.

Below is the output from --list-modules where java.sql is clearly available.

```
java.base@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.compiler@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.datatransfer@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.desktop@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.instrument@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.logging@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.management@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.management.rmi@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.naming@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.net.http@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.prefs@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.rmi@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.scripting@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.se@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.security.jgss@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.security.sasl@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.smartcardio@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.sql@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.sql.rowset@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.transaction.xa@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.xml@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
java.xml.crypto@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.accessibility@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.aot@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.attach@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.charsets@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.compiler@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.crypto.cryptoki@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.crypto.ec@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.crypto.mscapi@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.dynalink@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.editpad@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.hotspot.agent@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.httpserver@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.internal.ed@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.internal.jvmstat@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.internal.le@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.internal.opt@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.internal.vm.ci@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.internal.vm.compiler@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jartool@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.javadoc@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jcmd@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jconsole@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jdeps@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jdi@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jdwp.agent@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jfr@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jlink@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jshell@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jsobject@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.jstatd@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.localedata@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.management@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.management.agent@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.management.jfr@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.naming.dns@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.naming.rmi@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.net@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.pack@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.rmic@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.scripting.nashorn@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.sctp@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.security.auth@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.security.jgss@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.unsupported@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.unsupported.desktop@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.xml.dom@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
jdk.zipfs@11.0.4-ojdkbuild
javafx.base file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar
javafx.controls file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar
javafx.fxml file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.fxml.jar
javafx.graphics file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
javafx.media file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.media.jar
javafx.swing file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.swing.jar
javafx.swt file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx-swt.jar automatic
javafx.web file:///C:/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.web.jar
```

Because most of our internal dependencies are still Java 8, with a lot of duplicate definitions and split packages we would like to avoid explicitly declaring our projects as modules.

I've read something about gson not being released after some PR was approved, but can it really be that gson is running behind?

What is the best option if we ultimately have to switch from gson?

Comment: The java.sql module is mapped to the platform class loader. Is it possible that the URLClassLoader in your stack trace is created with a parent of "null" by mistake?

Comment: I will check and see if I can confirm or deny that because that would be a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some troubleshooting the error appears to be a combination of the "classpath file" classpath shortener found in IntelliJ (version 2018, removed in 2019) and our use of the org.reflections library.

Whenever we used a different classpath shortener all our plugins would stop loading (in our application) but java.sql would be accessible.

The solution was to use another classpath shortener (the classpath file is removed in IntelliJ 2019) and switch to the ClassGraph library for reflections (https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph).

Now we are able to use any classpath shortener and still have reflections working in Java 11.

My suspicion is that when using the other classpath shorteners the top-level URLClassLoader has only one URL to a jar or file containing the full classpath. This apparently causes issues for org.reflections but is handled properly by ClassGraph.